# Ubuntu 3D not working

Tags: 11.10, 3d

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 on Virtualbox 4.1.4 with an i7 dual-core MacBook Pro 15" and 8 GB RAM. While Ubuntu 11.04 was running fine with the 3d option, the new 11.10 version is not working.

Comment: is your version supported at all? google the exact model.

Comment: If you want to get the 3D cube working correctly try the method from [this blog](http://reformedmusings.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/howto-get-the-compiz-desktop-cube-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty-and-unity/) I have no idea if it still works for 11.10 though..

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)